# Create <div> or <li> item dynamically from click with predetermined values (database)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, mysql

Basically, I need to create div and/or li items with **unique** ID's and values from form input and button click.

For example, if I want to choose the duck-div, I'll search for it in the input search bar, choose it and click "add". The duck-div would have a duck in the background and other div's other animals. Well, animals aren't my goal, but you get the point.

This far I've accomplished creating **< div >** and **< li >** dynamically via either jQuery **append** and JavaScript **create**, but those are all with same ID's and values. They're clones. I need to create unique divs, but I don't even know where to go from here.

Thank you so much for any help

***P.S.*** If you don't know how to create it, but you know what programming language it is related to - please let me know! I'm pretty good at figuring stuff out, but I have currently no idea even what language I need to search the solution from. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I dontn get the point. Can you explain better?

Comment: Can you show us what you've got already that doesn't work? Where are the `id` and `value` attributes coming from that's making them the same? And this is, probably, best-solved in JavaScript (in the client-side). But to make solutions that fit with your (corrected) code we'd need to see that code. Please, help us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something like this:

```
function makeDuck() {
  var duckCount = $('.duck').length;
  var duckId = 'duck'+duckCount;
  $('<div class="duck">').attr('id',duckId).appendTo('body');
}
```

When you create a duck div you give it a class of "duck". That lets you count the number of existing "duck" divs before creating a new one and use that count to generate a unique id.

And here's a more generic function for creating any species of animal.

```
function makeAnimal(species) {
  var id = species + $('.'+species).length;
  $('<div>').attr('class',species).attr('id',id).appendTo('body');
}
```

Comment: Now that I read it myself, I think I explained it really bad. So what I'm after is that I have in storage a set with different divs. Each div is different, and the user can choose which one to dynamically create by search form. He can then proceed to create that div by clicking the button. Thanks so much for helping.

`<input id="autocomplete"> <input class="searchbutton" type="submit" value="Add"> <ul id="sortable"> <li class="item">Item 1</li> <li class="item">Item 2</li> </ul>`

`$('.searchbutton').click(function(){ $('#sortable').append($('<li>', { text: $('#autocomplete').val() })); });`

Comment: What do you mean when you say you have a set of different divs in storage? Are there a bunch of hidden divs on the page with different ids and you want to select one based on the id the user enters in the input field and then add it to the list?

Comment: Kind of like what Facebook has in their "Likes" -page. The user can search for the elements in the search input and then decorate their page with them. And the divs (or `<li>` would stay there when they log in next time.)

I'm not necessarily searching for the code for it, because it can be quite complex, but even a hint to what programming language might give me the answers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks so much for your help this far

Comment: I understand what you're asking now, but that sort of question is probably considered too open ended for stackoverflow. You're going to need javascript on the front end for the element selection. You're going to need some backend code (php, java, .net - whatwever you prefer) to save the user's selection and regenerate the page. And you'll probably also need a database of some sort to store the user selection.

Comment: After your comment I've looked into php and AJAX and I think I can accomplish it with these. Thanks a lot for pointing me to the right direction!